# Deserialization Error when Using RestTemplate with ResponseEntity in Microservice Communication

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, microservices

I am working on implementing communication between two microservices, where **Microservice 1 sends requests to Microservice 2** using `RestTemplate`. In Microservice 1, I am encountering an issue when trying to deserialize the response using `ResponseEntity<Greeting>`. Strangely, it works fine when using `ResponseEntity<Object>`. However, I need the response as an instance of the Greeting class, so using `ResponseEntity<Object>` is not really useful.

So what am I missing? What do I need to do differently in order to successfully deserialize the response as a Greeting object?

**I am receiving the following error message:**

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Type definition error: [...Greeting]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: 
Cannot construct instance of `...Greeting` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist):
Cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator) at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 2]
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException:
Type definition error: [simple type, class ...Greeting];
nested exception is .fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException:
Cannot construct instance of Greeting` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist):
cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
```

**Function to call in Microservice 1 (in class `GreetingsController`):**

```
...
@Autowired
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

@Bean
public RestTemplate getRestTemplate() {
    return new RestTemplate();
}

@ResponseBody
public Greeting getGreeting() {
    ....
    HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    requestHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(requestHeaders);
    // This one does not work
    //ResponseEntity<Greeting> response = restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:8081/greetings", HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, Greeting.class, "get");
    // only the following works
    ResponseEntity<Object> response = restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:8081/greetings", HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, Object.class, "get");
    ...
    return response.getBody(); 
}
```

**And here is the Greeting class in Microservice 1:**

```
// some imports here
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Greeting {
    @NotBlank
    private Integer id;
    @NonNull
    private String text;
}
```

I have attempted various online tutorials and experimented with different methods provided by RestTemplate, such as `restTemplate.getForObject()`, `restTemplate.getForEntity()`, and `restTemplate.exchange()`. Unfortunately, none of these approaches have worked in combination with the Greeting class.

Comment: Can you show me the response json when I request the RestTemplate?

Comment: You need to add the `@NoArgsConstructor` for Jackson. It creates an empty object and uses reflection to populate it. When it says "no default constructor" in Java it means it needs one without any params, when you add `@AllArgsConstructor` the default is removed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This should work.

```
    HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    requestHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);            
    HttpEntity<?> requestEntity=new HttpEntity<>(requestHeaders);             
    ParameterizedTypeReference<Greeting> responseType =  new ParameterizedTypeReference<Greeting>() {};    
    ResponseEntity<Greeting> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(yourUrl,HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity,responseType); 
    return response.getBody();
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. The key was `@NoArgsConstructor` as @DCTID said. After this, yours works too. Thanks :=